# RPi.GPIO interrupt not calling function long enough

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, character, gpio, lcd

So I'm trying to design an LCD screen to have a Menu and a bunch of different functions and its supposed to take 4 buttons. A select, a menu, and an up and down. Right now I'm just trying to work on the Menu button. I want it to always display the clock unless the menu button is pressed. But when I press the button it doesn't stay on screen for the 5 seconds it's supposed to. I have no idea why it wont either. I've looked up the RPi interrupt and followed it, but it still won't stay up. The "hi" appears for not even half a second. I'm also using the raspberry pi spy's LCD library which I can link if needed be. The only thing I did was modify some timing things to match those of my displays and added the abilty to add text to any of the four rows at once seeings that I have a 20x4 display. If someone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
#!usr/bin/python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/Downloads')
import lcd

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


lcd.lcd_init()

def start():
    for x in range(0,8):
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}>----TestOS----<{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}<>---TestOS-----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-<>--TestOS-----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}--<>-TestOS-----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}---<>TestOS-----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}----<TestOS>----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-----TestOS<>---{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-----TestOS-<>--{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-----TestOS--<>-{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-----TestOS---<>{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)


    lcd.lcd_init()

    for x in range(0,120):
        lcd.lcd_byte(0xFF,True)

    time.sleep(5)
    lcd.lcd_init()


def Menu():
    lcd.lcd_init()
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_1, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("hi", 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("hi", 1)
    time.sleep(5)

def clock():
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_1, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("+------------------+", 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string(time.strftime("|%I:%M %p          |"), 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_3, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string(time.strftime("|%a, %b %d, %Y |"), 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_4, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("+------------------+", 1)
    time.sleep(1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_1, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("+------------------+", 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string(time.strftime("|%I %M %p          |"), 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_3, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string(time.strftime("|%a, %b %d, %Y |"), 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_4, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("+------------------+", 1)
    time.sleep(1)

GPIO.add_event_detect(11, GPIO.FALLING, callback=Menu, bouncetime=100)

start()
try:
    while True:
        clock()

finally:
    lcd.lcd_init()
    lcd.GPIO.cleanup()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

PS:The lcd.lcd_init doubles to clear the screen which is why I call it so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your method clock() which is running in infinite loop, always override text on display with time.

You must stop clock() method when Menu() function runs.

I added global variable menu pressed:

```
#!usr/bin/python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/Downloads')
import lcd

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

menupressed = False

lcd.lcd_init()

def start():
    for x in range(0,8):
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}>----TestOS----<{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}<>---TestOS-----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-<>--TestOS-----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}--<>-TestOS-----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}---<>TestOS-----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}----<TestOS>----{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-----TestOS<>---{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-----TestOS-<>--{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-----TestOS--<>-{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
        lcd.lcd_string("[}-----TestOS---<>{]", 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)


    lcd.lcd_init()

    for x in range(0,120):
        lcd.lcd_byte(0xFF,True)

    time.sleep(5)
    lcd.lcd_init()


def Menu():
    global menupressed
    menupressed = True
    lcd.lcd_init()
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_1, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("hi", 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("hi", 1)
    time.sleep(5)
    menupressed = False

def clock():
    if(menupressed):
         return #when menu button is pressed, return - dont show nothing on display
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_1, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("+------------------+", 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string(time.strftime("|%I:%M %p          |"), 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_3, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string(time.strftime("|%a, %b %d, %Y |"), 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_4, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("+------------------+", 1)
    time.sleep(1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_1, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("+------------------+", 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string(time.strftime("|%I %M %p          |"), 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_3, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string(time.strftime("|%a, %b %d, %Y |"), 1)
    lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_4, lcd.LCD_CMD)
    lcd.lcd_string("+------------------+", 1)
    time.sleep(1)

GPIO.add_event_detect(11, GPIO.FALLING, callback=Menu, bouncetime=100)

start()
try:
    while True:
        clock()

finally:
    lcd.lcd_init()
    lcd.GPIO.cleanup()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Hope it was helpful

Comment: So, now it does stay on the screen for the 5 seconds its supposed to but, now it calls it twice before going back to the clock. And I tried to figure it out but I dont have any clue why

Comment: Does it run twice everytime? Did you try to increase bounce time? I have no other idea.

Comment: What type of LCD display are you using?

Comment: I tried the bouncetime and nothing changed. The site for the display is adafru.it/198

Comment: I should have one at home. I will try this code when I will have more time.